# Modeling, Looking for a quicker way to achieve a smooth transition between 2 shape

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

Hi. Is there a non destructive method to create a model where it gradual change between 2 different shape, for example a cylinder to a plane?

The model shown in the images is a door handle I found online, I am trying to look for an alternative workflow to achieve such shape. Where it start of as as 1 shape(Circle as seen in the images) and gradually change to another (a plane as seen in the images).

Currently, my method is to bridge the 2 shape and manually tweak it. It took a long time to complete. Hence, I am looking for a potential alternative.